# I'd like to get a new line in my textfile

Tags: php, phpexcel

I tried to get a new line in my for loop now for quite a while, the answer will probably be pretty simple, but I wasn't able to figure it out myself.

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    $data .= $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue();
}
file_put_contents('file.txt',$data);
```

My output is:

```
Website1Website2Website3Website4
```

While it has to be:

```
Website1
Website2
Website3
Website4
```

Comment: @treyBake I can't believe none of the answers mentioned `PHP_EOL`!

Comment: @Nick I'm surprised too, been around since 5.0.2, woulda thought it would be at the forefront of line breaks since then :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a `PHP_EOL` to each string. From the [manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php):

> PHP_EOL (string)
>
> The correct 'End Of Line' symbol for this platform

Try this:

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
    $data .= $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
}
file_put_contents('file.txt',$data);
```

By using `PHP_EOL` instead of `"\n"` or `"\r\n"` you will improve the portability of your code.

Comment: @IceWhiteWood no worries - I hope it was helpful.

Comment: Lucas's and your answer both worked for me :)

Comment: @IceWhiteWood good to hear. As I mentioned, using `PHP_EOL` is a more portable solution and will ensure that your code works properly on Unix, Mac or Windows systems.

Comment: Ah okay, I understand. I am building a tool to optimize the proces of linkbuilding. My next step is to deduplicate the values that are in the textfile. But I guess there is a lot of information on the internet about that subject :)

Comment: @IceWhiteWood you might find it easier to set up `$data` as an array and write each value into there, and then use `array_unique` to get the unique values before writing to the file.

Comment: Without knowing what the purpose of writing this data to a file is, I don’t think there’s any reason to over-hype PHP_EOL like that. If that file was f.e. to be _downloaded_ by users on different systems, then what’s the relevance of what the _generating_ system thinks was the “correct” version of a line break …? On the contrary, you might have _less_ problems in that kind of scenario, if you explicitly _specify_ what kind of “line break” exactly you want.

Comment: @04FS if the user wants to open the file in another application on the same system then having the correct line breaks will make that work better.

Comment: Hmm I think that will be better indeed @Nick I am going to try to work with array_unique before putting everything in the file. Thanks!

Comment: @nick and if they didn’t, but it was actually the opposite – then it will make it work “less better” … My point being, it depends on the situation.

Comment: @04FS you are correct; there will be situations where one is better than the other, and I guess it's up to OP to figure out which one is better for his situation.

Answer (score 0):

[Concatenate](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/concatenation-two-string-php/) a line break in your string.

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
        $data .= $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue() . "\n";
    }
file_put_contents('file.txt',$data);
```

or use [PHP_EOL](https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.constants.php)

```
for ($row = 2; $row <= $lastRow; $row++) {
        $data .= $worksheet->getCell('A'.$row)->getValue() . PHP_EOL;
    }
file_put_contents('file.txt',$data);
```

Comment: This works for me. Thanks a lot, you are the hero of the day!

Comment: Glad to help :D